# tonton tontaine et re tonton -- what does it mean?

Tags: vocabulaire

I’m reading *A l'ombre d'un marronnier* by Pierre Béarn , the last line confused me

> tonton tontaine et re tonton

What does it mean? I know *tonton* can mean *uncle* but it doesn’t look so here, also *tontaine* and *re* doesn’t ring a bell.

Are these just onomatopoeiae?

The full content of the poem is as below

> A l'ombre d'un marronnier
>
> Pierre Béarn
>
> Un vaillant chêne en un été
> avait pondu dix mille glands
> qui glandouillaient gland gland gland
> à qui naîtrait demain dans l'herbe...
>
> Non loin de lui un marronnier
> n'avait réussi qu'un marron
> qui devint vite un avorton
> cerné par deux cents menus chênes.
>
> Mais l'an d'après quand vint l'été
> le marronnier reprit vigueur
> et déployant son plafonnier
> vite étouffa sous sa touffeur
> tous ces intrus mal aérés
> afin de semer ses marrons
> tonton tontaine et re tonton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have no meaning, they are just a repetition of words chosen for the sound they produce when pronounced, the alliteration and the rhyme. They are more like an onomatopoeia.

A very similar repetition can be found in the famous *[Malbrough s'en va-t-en guerre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbrough_s%27en_va-t-en_guerre)* where each stanza contains:

> Malbrough s'en va-t-en guerre
> **Mironton, tonton, mirontaine**
> Malbrough s'en va-t-en guerre
> Ne sait quand reviendra.
> Ne sait quand reviendra
> [...]

Comment: Isn't it "mironton, tonton, mirontaine"?

Comment: @Frank It is indeed, fixed.

Comment: Ça marche aussi avec _mironton_, ceci dit. Ça fait longtemps que je n'ai plus chanté cette chanson, en fait hahaha ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar phrase in some lines of poetry, from The King in Yellow, spoken by an apparently ghostly huntress in the marshes of Britanny to a lost American hunter who is about to become her guest for the night,

Chasseur, chasseur, chassez encore,
Quittez Rosette et Jeanneton,
Tonton, tonton, tontaine, tonton,
Ou, pour, rabattre, dès l'aurore,
Que les Amours soient de planton,
Tonton, tontaine, tonton

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "What does it mean?...Are these just onomatopoeiae?"